# ie11 Element.children polyfill

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project in which I use es6 code with babel.
I use the following code:

```
 let result= xmlDocument.querySelector("xmlNodeSelector");

 for (let child of  result.children) { /* do something */ }
```

The problem it doens't work on IE11 since no children property.

I create the following polyfill but it didn't help:

```
if(Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('children')){
            return;
        }

        Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'children', {
            get: function(){

                let children = new HTMLCollection();

                for(let i=0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++){
                    let item = this.childNodes[i];

                    if(item.nodeName !== '#text'){
                        children.push(item);
                    }
                }

                return children;
            }
        });
```

When I debug IE11 I can see the prototype is Element but the property is not added. In addition when using:

```
selectorResult instanceof Element
selectorResult instanceof Node
```

I get false on both.

At the moment I use a method to extract children rather then adding to the prototype which is what i prefer.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please click the `<>` button and add a [mcve]

Comment: added more code before for...of loop

Comment: IE11 has children property, but only on html Elements. This is why you polyfill don't help.

Answer (score 2):

The following code adds the property `children` to all HTML,XML and SVG elements - just tested it under IE11:

```
//make sure we have Node.children and Element.children available
(function (constructor) {
    if (constructor &&
        constructor.prototype &&
        constructor.prototype.children == null) {
        Object.defineProperty(constructor.prototype, 'children', {
            get: function () {
                var i = 0, node, nodes = this.childNodes, children = [];
                //iterate all childNodes
                while (node = nodes[i++]) {
                    //remenber those, that are Node.ELEMENT_NODE (1)
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) { children.push(node); }
                }
                return children;
            }
        });
    }
  //apply the fix to all HTMLElements (window.Element) and to SVG/XML (window.Node)
})(window.Node || window.Element);
```

I found that polyfill on MDN.

This polyfill will return an `array`, instead of an `HTMLCollection`, but you can still make use of `Node.children.length` and `Node.children[index]`.

Using this polyfill you could iterate your result like this:

```
var resChildren = result.children
var index, maxindex;
for (index=0, maxindex=resChildren.length; index<maxindex; index++) 
{
    /* do_something_with(resChildren[index]); */
}
```